# Lumen QueryException write to log

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5.3, lumen, lumen-5.3

I'm using Lumen 5.3.* and I need to make `QueryException` write errors on the `storage/logs/lumen.log`.

Other validations are writing to the log file except for `QueryException`.

```
try {
    // throw here exception here
} catch (QueryException $e) {
    // do what ever
} catch (CustomException $e) {
    // do what ever
}
```

I have my `CustomException` extended to `\Exception` and use `Handler` class to to do `report()` as to why I am able to write to the log file. But the `QueryException` does not. (`QueryException` is a lumen vendor file)

I know it is possible to just to `\Log()` upon catch on the `QueryException` but I want to make things cleaner by not putting it this way.

Is there another way to do this aside from doing what was stated above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if you have debug mode enabled `APP_DEBUG`

Comment: It is. `QueryException` is not extended to `Handler` in which handles the report and render.

Comment: From what checked inside the source, the `QueryException` by default is caught and the query is rerun in case it was due to connection loss. The exception maybe disabled by default to prevent logging of sensitive data from the database.

Comment: Does it mean that `QueryException` does not really log exceptions to prevent logging sensitive data?

Comment: Checking into [owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Error_Handling,_Auditing_and_Logging), I see no rule regarding not logging of query exception errors.

Comment: Alright i just did a fresh install of lumen 5.3.3 and guess what, the logging works just fine for `QueryException`. Since it extends `PDOException` you seen that as well. It's something on your end.

Comment: Do you mean that when a `QueryException` occurs, it writes it on the `lumen.log` file?